# Facebook SDK for PHP 4.0.0 login logout issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am a PHP developer and what I want is firstly user come to my website and login using Facebook login then I want to redirect user to specific page and get access token and then call to Graph API to access user's data. I have divided it into 2 steps

1) Make user to login using Facebook, It's done and code is given below:

```
include_once('facebook-php-sdk-v4-master/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
include_once('facebook-php-sdk-v4-master/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once( 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-master/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-master/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-master/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-master/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-master/src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-master/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
session_start();
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP id', 'APP key');
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://redirect-url.com/');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
echo "<a href=".$loginUrl.">FB login here</a>";
```

2) Get token detail on redirect URL, which is incomplete
Can anyone please help me how can I get this detail ?????

Answer (score 0):

[See the following tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/) on how to handle login and sessions correctly.

To get the token after redirect, you need to so the following:

```
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
```

Then, check if the session is valid and redirect as needed:

```
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // user is logged in, display logout link
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://yourwebsite.com/app/logout.php' ) . '">Logout</a>';
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends' ) ) . '">Login</a>';
}
```

Comment: Why that is logging out from facebook too?

Comment: That's the way it works. If you just want to log them out of the app, delete the session.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was going getting the same error.

Found another method to get session information on another page.
On first page

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret,$cookie);

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();



try {
  $session = $helper->getSession();


  $_SESSION['token'] = $session->getToken();

}
```

On the second page it should be

```
$token = $_SESSION["token"];

$session = new FacebookSession($token);
```